# C++ для системного программирования

Tags: библиотеки, c++

День добрый. Интересует такой вопрос: какие нужно изучить библиотеки c++ для системного программирования и еще какие-нибудь вещи посоветуйте, чтобы вникнуть в эту сферу. Недавно начал изучать Qt. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: нужно изучать ядро нужной операционной системы - это и будет "нужной библиотекой". И учить С. Вот он как раз наиболее важен.

Comment: > И учить С. Вот он как раз наиболее важен.

Си не нужен.

Comment: Дак при изучении плюсов хочешь, не хочешь, а Си выучишь..